# Sequelize - 1:M relationships with custom foreignKey not deleting on cascade

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models: `User` and `Profile`

Initially, I set up the association of `User` with `Profile`:

```js
User.Profile = User.hasOne(models.Profile, {
    as: "profile",
    foreignKey: "userId",
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
```

I set up a test to check the associations between the models

```js
const user = await User.create(
    {
        email: "test@example.com",
        password: bcrypt.hashSync("password", 10),
        role: "basic",
        profile: ...,
    },
    { include: ["profile"] }
);

// Check amount of entries created
expect(await User.count()).toBe(1);
expect(await Profile.count()).toBe(1);

// Check associations
expect(user.profile).toBeTruthy();


// Delete the user
await user.destroy();

// Check amount of entries deleted
expect(await User.count()).toBe(0);
expect(await Profile.count()).toBe(0);
```

So far everything ok. Now I want to make sure that the association works both ways. So I add the following association to the Profile model:

```js
Profile.User = Profile.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: "userId",
    as: "user",
});
```

I have to add manually the foreignKey as `userId` because otherwise it searches for a field `UserId`, with uppercase "U", since the table "User" is in PascalCase

But now, the tests that I were already passing, suddenly fail:

```
{
    name: 'SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError',
    parent: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed] {
        errno: 19,
        code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
        sql: 'DELETE FROM `Users` WHERE `id` = 1'
    },
    original: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed] {
        errno: 19,
        code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
        sql: 'DELETE FROM `Users` WHERE `id` = 1'
    },
    sql: 'DELETE FROM `Users` WHERE `id` = 1',
    parameters: {},
    table: undefined,
    fields: undefined,
    value: undefined,
    index: undefined,
    reltype: undefined
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

**OTHER FILES**

For reference, this is how the migrations for "User" and "Profile" look like:

```js
"use strict";
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable("Users", {
            id: { allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
            // ... other fields
        });
    },
    async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable("Users");
    },
};
```

```js
"use strict";
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable("Profiles", {
            id: { allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
            userId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                references: { model: "Users", key: "id" },
                onUpdate: "CASCADE",
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
            },
            // ... other fields
        });
    },
    async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable("Profiles");
    },
};
```

Comment: Try one of following solutions: 1) `{ onDelete: 'cascade', hooks:true }`  - hooks expected to call destroy on references before destroying parent. 2) manually add `User.beforeDestroy(async user => {
  await Profile.destroy({ where: { userId: user.id } })
})`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not solution to `CASCADE DELETE`, but it's my opinion which solves current case.

Based on many debates in StackOverflow I understood that Sequelize may not act as expected when you define foreign keys.
It may be also depending from MySQL db also.

As programmer (not db engineer) I prefer to take control on processes explicitly instead of "let db handle other stuff".

So I would recommend to add before destroy hook to User model to have control on delete logic, instead of trusting it to db:

```
User.beforeDestroy(async user => {   
  await Profile.destroy({ where: { userId: user.id } });
  // also can add extra operations like logging and etc here...
});
```

Read about it in [INSTANCE HOOKS](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/#instance-hooks)

Another solution is not really delete records, but hide them using Sequelize's [PARANOID MODE](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/paranoid/) - this way I prefer the most, cause in practice users suddenly delete data, so I can always put back `deletedAt` field to `null` and data will be recovered.

> Sequelize supports the concept of paranoid tables. A paranoid table is one that, when told to delete a record, it will not truly delete it. Instead, a special column called deletedAt will have its value set to the timestamp of that deletion request.
>
> This means that paranoid tables perform a soft-deletion of records, instead of a hard-deletion.

Comment: You mean that I should skip all together the SQL concept of cascade, and implement it myself?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent yes, cause all logic, all "what You means" are in Your code, not hidden inside db schemas. + You can add extra operations to Your code to log something, to do some other operations like copying Profile to DeletedProfiles, copying User to DeletedUsers and then do real delete (gives recoverability).  DB level is something which is not in Your control, so if You want control Your data - then You have to look at db as data storage. For example in my practice I don't deleted data, I put deleted flag and do set `deleted: true` so I don't have issues with such cases. But up to You.